# Convergence of sum of random variables to the normal distribution

Tags: summation, random-variables, central-limit-theorem

The classical CLT speaks about the convergence of centered and normed sum of random variables to the standard normal variable. But what about the convergence of noncentered and nonnormed sum of r.v.s'?
Im my case I have that $X_k\sim N(0,\frac{C}{n})$ (where $C>0$, $n$ is an integer) and then I need a limit of the distribution of the following sum:
$$S_n=n\sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k^3$$
The expectation of $S_N$ is $0$, variance is $n^2\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{15C^3}{n^3}=15C^2$. So the variance is always constant. 
working with the distribution function of $X^3$ is not practical - no closed expressions can be obtained for the characteristic function. In case of centered and normed $S_n$ CLT provides a limit. But is it true that the sum $S_n$ itself converge to the normal distribution with parameters $(0,15C^2)$? The computer simulation studies shows that for large $n$ this is a valid approximation. But maybe it isn't true in the limit?

Comment: The variance is $n^2\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{15C^3}{k^3}\sim C'n^2$ so the variance is not constant.

Comment: @Did Actually, no. For each integer $n$ we have $n$ independent random normal variables with variance $\frac{C}{n}$, i.e. dependent only on the number $n$ but not on the index of that random variable. Therefore $Var(X_i^3)=\frac{C^3}{n^3}$. Hence  $n^2\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{15C^3}{n^3}=15C^2$

Comment: Thus each $X_k$ is actually some $X_{k,n}$? Then $X_{k,n}=\sqrt{C/n}Y_k$ where $(Y_k)$ is i.i.d. standard normal and $S_n=C\sqrt{C}\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\sum\limits_{k=1}^nY_k^3$ and the most usual CLT applies.

Comment: @Did Great! I completely overthough the problem. Thanks. Could you make it into an answer - I'll accept it.